# Gremlin query not working - 2 x vertex if doesn't exist and add edge

Tags: gremlin, gremlin-server, azure-cosmosdb-gremlinapi

I'm using gremlin and have the statement below. I want to:

- create a vertex if one does not exist
- create another vertex if one does not exist
- create an edge between the verticies

The edge doesn't get created.  I'd really appreciate help with the logic/approach here.

```
    g.V().has('User','refId','435').
        fold().coalesce(unfold(),addV(label, 'User').
    property('name','John Smith').property('refId','435'))
        .as('user').
        V().has('JobTitle','name','Advisor').
        fold().coalesce(unfold(),addV(label,'JobTitle').
property('name','Advisor'))
.as('jobtitle').
    addE('REGISTERED_AS').from('user').to('jobtitle')
```

Comment: Please could you add the complete query (it is truncated) and it would be good in general to include a description of the backend graph database you are using and any additional examples and commentary to make the question more complete.

Comment: @KelvinLawrence I've updated above.  Issue with this is the edge is not created between the vertices.

Comment: You cannot just provide a list of strings to `addV()`. You need to use the `property()` step the way you were in your previous example. Also it would be much easier to read your query if you split it up over multiple lines.

Comment: @KelvinLawrence thanks .  I've updated that however the edge still does not get created.  Can you help fix this please?

Answer (score 1):

Given your most recent comment on Kfir's answer that includes your latest code, I think that there are several problems to correct with your approach. First note that `addV()` does not take a long list of labels and properties. I'm surprised that didn't generate an error for you. `addV()` just takes the vertex label as an argument and then you use `property()` to provide the associated key/value pairs.

```
g.V().has('User', 'refId', '435').
      fold().
      coalesce(unfold(), 
               addV('User').
                 property('name', 'John Smith').property('refId', '435').property('firstName', 'John').
                 property('lastName', 'Smith').property('JobTitle', 'Chief Executive Officer')).as('user').
      V().has('JobTitle', 'name', 'Advisor').
      fold().
      coalesce(unfold(), addV(label, 'JobTitle', 'name', 'Advisor')).as('jobtitle').
      V().
      addE('REGISTERED_AS').
        from('user').
        to('jobtitle')
```

There is an extra `V()` right before `addE()` which would basically call `addE()` for every vertex you have in your graph rather than just for the one vertex to which you want to add an edge.

```
g.V().has('User', 'refId', '435').
      fold().
      coalesce(unfold(), 
               addV('User').
                 property('name', 'John Smith').property('refId', '435').property('firstName', 'John').
                 property('lastName', 'Smith').property('JobTitle', 'Chief Executive Officer')).as('user').
      V().has('JobTitle', 'name', 'Advisor').
      fold().
      coalesce(unfold(), addV(label, 'JobTitle', 'name', 'Advisor')).as('jobtitle').
      addE('REGISTERED_AS').
        from('user').
        to('jobtitle')
```

So, now things look syntax correct but there is a problem and it stems from this:

```
gremlin> g.V(1).as('x').fold().unfold().addE('self').from('x').to('x')
The provided traverser does not map to a value: v[1]->[SelectOneStep(last,x)]
Type ':help' or ':h' for help.
Display stack trace? [yN]
```

The path information in the traversal is lost after the a reducing step (i.e. `fold()`) so you can't select back to "x" after that. You need to reform your traversal a bit to not require the `fold()`:

```
g.V().has('User', 'refId', '435').
      fold().
      coalesce(unfold(), 
               addV('User').
                 property('name', 'John Smith').property('refId', '435').property('firstName', 'John').
                 property('lastName', 'Smith').property('JobTitle', 'Chief Executive Officer')).as('user').
      coalesce(V().has('JobTitle', 'name', 'Advisor'),
               addV('JobTitle').property('name', 'Advisor')).as('jobtitle').
      addE('REGISTERED_AS').
        from('user').
        to('jobtitle')
```

That really just means using `coalesce()` more directly without the `fold()` and `unfold()` pattern. You really only need that pattern at the start of a traversal to ensure that a traverser stays alive in the stream (i.e. if the user doesn't exist `fold()` produces an empty list which becomes the new traverser and the traversal will continue executing).

Answer (score 0):

The question code is partial. Some alignment would help.

Nevertheless, I think your problem is in the `as('jobtitle')`, which is inside the `coalesce` statement. That is, if the vertex exists, we don't get to the second traversal and the `as` statement is not executed. Same for the `as('user')`.

To solve, just move the `as` statements outside the `coalesce`.

Comment: Thanks for this @Kfir Dadosh.  I've changed to move the statement outside however still doesn't create the edge.  Further thoughts?
Here's the latest:
g.V().has('User','refId','435').fold().coalesce(unfold(),addV(label, 'User', 'name','John Smith', 'refId', '435','firstName','John'   ,'lastName','Smith','JobTitle','Chief Executive Officer')).as('user').V().has('JobTitle','name','Advisor').fold().coalesce(unfold(),addV(label, 'JobTitle', 'name','Advisor')).as('jobtitle').V().addE('REGISTERED_AS').from('user').to('jobtitle')

Comment: can you help with the query above please?